# JSConsole showing console messages in weird order when debugging Cordova app in mobile device

Tags: javascript, debugging, cordova, console

I've been using [JSConsole](http://jsconsole.com/) to debug a PhoneGap/Cordova application but it seems to be showing messages from the console in a different order than it's supposed to be, not making sense.

Is [JSConsole](http://jsconsole.com/) a reliable tool to debug PhoneGap/Cordova applications via mobile devices or am I missing something?

Comment: What platform are you debugging on? If you can, I'd use either Chrome's remote debugging or Safari's remote debugging -- much easier.

Comment: I'm debugging on an iMac and running the app on mainly two devices: an Android 4.0.3 device (Galaxy Tab GT-P3100) and on an iPhone 4 iOS 7. Thanks for the tip! I'll check it out.

Comment: iOS 7 will work fine with Safari. You need Android 4.4 to do Chrome debugging, but you can get the equivalent by purchasing jsHybugger (https://www.jshybugger.com), which lets you use Chrome inspection on Android < 4.4. (It has a free trial which limits sessions to 2 minutes.)

Comment: hey Kerri, I won't purchase jshybugger since i was not able to test it  (it says in their page you can use the trial version for 2 minutes, but I couldn't try it more than once, even after rebuilding the app). So I'm back to JsConsole facing this same problem (console messages order not making sense).

Comment: Try weinre or debug.phonegap.com -- that should also have console logs that can help (though no support for breakpoints etc.). Try just sending a series of console logs in sequence from a simple function (say, console.log(1); console.log(2); ...) -- do those appear in order?